# Include nodejs js module on client side

Tags: node.js

E.g. Using SimpleMDE. I've installed it to node modules, what's the right way to include it? Making the nodemodules/simplemde public seems like the wrong move. I'm using express and ejs.

Comment: making nodemodules/simplemde/dist public seams fine, you could also just find it on a cdn

Comment: Such as: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/simplemde